# Is that possible to yield item from pipeline in Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I was yielding new item fromm pipeline in scrapy.It seems not working.
for example:

```
class SessionListPipeline(MediaPipeline):
    def media_downloaded(self, response, request, info):
       yielditem= ItemLoader(item=ItemYieldToAnotherPipeline(),response=response)
       yield yielditem
```

here is another pipeline:

```
class AnotherPipeline(MediaPipeline):
    def media_downloaded(self, response, request, info):
       #here ,I can not get item of "ItemYieldToAnotherPipeline"
```

Both pipelines was enabled.Is that possible to do like this?How do you guys return item from pipeline?Very thanks for your answer.

Comment: See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#writing-your-own-item-pipeline for information on what a pipeline can do. They can return a *single* item from their `process_item` method, that’s it. If you need to yield multiple items, when you need to use a [spider middleware](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html) instead.

Comment: Thank you ,pipeline works as one by one,It's not impossible to return Item from pipeline.Your suggestion of "middleware" may do the work.